# How do I answer a question, "Is this...?"

Tags: questions

Suppose one is asked, "Is this the first time you have been to Britain?" What is the grammatically-correct reply?

> 1. No, I have.
> 2. Yes, it is.
> 3. Yes, I am.
> 4. Yes, I have.

Comment: The request for resources which this question originally contained is answered [on Meta](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/735/resources-for-learning-english).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The original question is:

> Is this the first time you have been to Britain?

The question refers to a specific instance of time. It's not referring to you yourself. Hence the correct answer would be:

> Yes, it is.

Here you're saying that **it** indeed is the first **time** you've been to Britain. Note again that it points back to time, and not to you.

Now, just to make things clearer.

> Yes, I have.

This answer points to you (yourself) traveling to Britain, and not a specific instance of time. So, the ideal question to this would be:

> Have **you** been to Britain before?

Now, the same question can also be replied in the negative, if you haven't traveled to Britain before. Then you reply something similar to your sentence 1(with a slight modification):

> No, I haven't

And lastly:

> Yes, I am

The use of "am" suggests a present, continuous action; something that is happening now (present tense). So, this would be a proper response to:

> Are you traveling to Britain?

Answer (score 0):

You should answer:

> Yes, it is.

That's because the question is primarily about *the first time or not* and this **does not** directly include you! And thus, the short answer won't contain ***'I'***.

Answer the question fully and you'll understand why does it take *'Yes, it is!'*

> Yes, it is the first time I have been to Britain.

Note: I'd frame this sentence as: *Yes, it is *for* the first time, I've been to Britain.*

Comment: I doubt that many native speakers would use 'Yes, it is for the first time, I've been to Britain.' I can't find any evidence of that exact expression on the internet, and I've never heard it in 60+ years _in_ Britain.

Comment: @Maulik V: What's the need for **for** in _Yes, it is for the first time, I've been to Britain._?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth What's that *exact* expression? The sentence is not copied from anywhere. As for the use of *for* in it is concerned, have a look -***It is for the first time** a former CJI is being appointed to a gubernatorial post* from [from The Hindu](http://www.thehindu.com/news/national/experts-divided-over-posting-of-excjis-as-governors/article6367634.ece); ***It is for the first time** the airline is celebrating the Air India Day.* [from The .UK site](http://www.ibtimes.co.uk/air-india-website-crashes-national-carrier-offers-1-tickets-five-days-1462737). And, I'm not a native.

Comment: @ManishGiri That way, it looks natural *to me.* Also, such style's example is in my other comment.

Comment: @MaulikV There's a difference between the usage of **for** in _It is for the first time a former CJI is being appointed to a gubernatorial post_ and _Yes, it is for the first time, I've been to Britain_. While using **for** is necessary in the first sentence, and also in your other comment example, it's redundant in the _have been to Britain_ example. Unfortunately, I can't put my finger on the exact (technical) difference, just yet. All I can say is using **for** implies the importance of a former CJI being appointed for the **very first time**. This is not the case in OP's example.

Comment: @ManishGiri *It is the first time a chaiwala has become the Prime Minister of India.* - What's your opinion on this sentence?

Comment: I think I've made my point clear enough. If not, too bad. Not really possible to dissect every **for**-sentence you throw at me!

Comment: @Manish (1) Apologies for my earlier misreading of your name! (2) None of the examples containing 'for' you give sound colloquial in BrE. It seems a conflation of two common expressions: 'For the first time, a former journalist is being appointed to a managerial post' and 'It is the first time a former journalist has been appointed ...'. I think that, if such expressions are widely used in say Indian English, that caveat needs to be added.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I come across dozens of such sentences in Indian dailies, one of the limited sources I learn the language from.